Stop VS Code from creating files called "2" when debugging C/C++ over SSH
I'm using VS Code to debug C/C++ program over SSH. It creates nearly empty files called "2" in the working folder. Why? But more importantly - how to stop it? I'm constantly having to manually delete them.
The files seem to contain an escape code, and they are produced when debugging. I can't find any description about them. Maybe it's just me!

I suspect something related to shell syntax for stream redirection. I'd suggest raising an issue ticket at https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-cpptools/issues. If you do, please add a link here to your issue ticket.

I raised issue on VS Code GitHub: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-cpptools/issues/12639
